# what this method return?

Tags: java, generics

I am reading the following code,

```
public static <t> T getFirst(List<T> list)
```

I understand the `List<T> list`, the method get a reference to `List<T>` as parameter, and return 
an object with type `T`, but what about the `<t>` after the keyword public static?

what does this mean?

Comment: The `<t>` should probably be `<T>`, right?

Comment: @Aleksi There is already a T in front of the getFirst();

Comment: Can you show the whole class/interface this is taken from? Is <t> used in the class definition (i.e. another generic)?

Comment: @Liv I just follow this tutorial http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/04/java-generics-quick-tutorial.html
and there is a class with <T>, but not t

Comment: see comments below, that is a type indeed, <t> should be <T>

Comment: It's a typo. <t> should be <T>.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`<t>` declares a type parameter. That means that the *method* has a type parameter that can change on each invocation.

*Unless* `T` is a concrete type in your project (which is unlikely), the `<t>` should be `<T>`.

So in plain english `<T> T getFirst(List<T> list)` means:

- there's a method called `getFirst`
- it has a type parameter `T` (i.e. an arbitrary type which is aliased to `T`)
- it takes a `List<T>` as its argument (i.e. a `List` of objects of that arbitrary type).
- it returns a `T` object (i.e. an instance of that arbitrary type).

If you just wrote `T getFirst(List<T> list)` then the meaning would change:

- there's a method called `getFirst`
- it takes a `List<T>` as its argument (i.e. a `List` of objects of the **concrete** type `T`)
- it returns an object of the concrete type `T`.

Answer (score 0):

It tells the compiler that `T` is not any concrete class but a placeholder for a class. Otherwise the compiler would think that `List<T>` is a list with elements of type `T`. I.e. it marks your method generic